# UnicodeDecodeError import csv into MySql DB

Tags: mysql, unicode

I try to load an absolute easy csv file into my db. I added the column "Success" to my csv file and now I get following error.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: Import data file: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

This is my csv file...

Spieltag;Heimtore;Awaytore;Heimteam;Awayteam;Success

1;3;2;4;2;1

2;1;5;2;1;4

And this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `resultate` (
  `Spieltag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Heimtore` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Auswärtstore` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Heimteam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Auswärtsteam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Saison` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1819',
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Ueber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Spieltag`,`Heimteam`,`Auswärtsteam`,`Saison`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=405 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

What the hell is wrong with my table or my csv file? I can't find the problem...

Comment: I'd guess your CSV file is UTF-8 encoded and instead of `Awaytore` the column name is really `Auswärtstore` like in the DB table. Change the encoding of the CSV file to ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 and then the import should work.

Comment: @Quagaar - How does one change the encoding of a file?  The CSV that is shown has _only_ characters that are identical in Ascii and Latin1 and UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 and windows-1252.

Comment: @Flamms -- Are there no accented letters in the CSV file?

Comment: Any decent editor shows and lets you change the encoding (e.g. Notepad++) and every IDE should do also. The thing that makes me think that your file contains Umlauts is that `C3A4` is the UTF-8 encoded code point of the unicode character `ä`.